# Multiple Modifiers

Tags: adverbs, negation

What does *not* modify in this sentence?

> I am not even playing basketball.

Also, does *quickly* modify *played the game* or just *played* in this sentence?

> I played the game quickly.

Comment: @Lawrence Does it modify *even*? *Even* is an intensifier here, surely. One might perhaps argue that it's not just *not* but *not even* as the modifier. Dan: please only ask one question at once: I'll leave it to you which one to remove (and it appears the first is the one to leave).

Comment: In the first sentence 'not' modifies the verb 'am playing' and makes the sentence a negative one. Without which the sentence will be a totally different one - a positive. In the second sentence 'quickly' modifies the whole sentence, though the focus is on the verb. Even without 'quickly', the sentence can stand without much change of meaning.

Comment: "Not" is modifying the focusing adverb "even", and the phrase "not even" then marks the clause as negative. In "I played the game quickly", the adverb "quickly" modifies the verb phrase "played the game".